# How to create a single onclick event for multiple div elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm still learning my way through all this stuff but what I was trying to do now was create a Tic-Tac-Toe game out of HTML, CSS & Javascript. However no matter what I try my onClick events won't run correctly. I just want the game to respond to the click by the player, send the identity of the tile clicked to the function so that it knows which one to change, and then change the tile's image (to either a nought or a cross).

I'm thinking that the best way to do this is have the onClick pass a different argument through depending on the `id` of the tile clicked but it's telling me that `placeTile()` isn't defined and besides there has to be an easier way to do it than the cocktail that I've conceived. Thanks for your help in advance! :)

The HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> Tic-Tac-Toe </title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='Tic-Tac-Toe.css'/>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='JQuery/jquery-1.11.1.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='Tic-Tac-Toe.js'></script>
</head>    

<body>
    <div id='game'>
        <div id='container'>
            <div id='board'>
                <div class='emptyTile' id='NW' onClick='placeTile("NW")'></div>
                <div class='emptyTile' id='N' onClick='placeTile("N")'></div>
                <div class='emptyTile' id='NE' onClick='placeTile("NE")'></div>
                <div class='emptyTile' id='W' onClick='placeTile("W")'></div>
                <div class='emptyTile' id='C' onClick='placeTile("C")'></div>
                <div class='emptyTile' id='E' onClick='placeTile("E")'></div>
                <div class='emptyTile' id='SW' onClick='placeTile("SW")'></div>
                <div class='emptyTile' id='S' onClick='placeTile("S")'></div>
                <div class='emptyTile' id='SE' onClick='placeTile("SE")'></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id='scores'>
            <div class='score' id='Score1'> Player 1: <br/> <span id='pOne' class='num'>0</span></div>
            <div class='score' id='Score2'> Player 2: <br/> <span id='pTwo' class='num'>0</span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The Javascript Function:

```
function placeTile(a){
    var tile = document.getElementById(a);
    if (currentPlayer == 0) {
        tile.removeClass('emptyTile');
        tile.addClass('cross');
        currentPlayer = 1;
    } else {
        tile.removeClass('emptyTile');
        tile.addClass('nought');
        currentPlayer = 0;
    }
}
```

So as you can see I'm doing this in a roundabout way, but the onclick event is supposed to pass the id of the div to the function, which is then used to make all the necessary changes to that div only and also swap the current player. But it is very messy and I;m sure I could clean it up somehow if I could just figure out how to make one javascript function react differently depending on what div is clicked...

Oh I love code but I also hate it too. It's addictive really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've included jQuery so use the click event as per this JSFiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/Delorian/3f2tvabo/

```
$('.emptyTile').click(function () {
    if (currentPlayer == 0) {
        $(this).removeClass('emptyTile');
        $(this).addClass('cross');
        currentPlayer = 1;
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass('emptyTile');
        $(this).addClass('nought');
        currentPlayer = 0;
    }});
```

You won't need anything on the HTML elements apart from the class to indicate a tile.

Comment: Yeah I actually tried just that but for whatever reason it wasn't calling the function when I tried it that way. I had a console log in the first line of it and I was never seeing that hit the console so I figured that for whatever reason it wasn't able to find it...

Comment: As per the Fiddle, it should work ok for you. Try it and if you have any issues, let me know. Otherwise mark this answer as correct if it does what you want.

Comment: I looked at the Fiddle and I think the issue may be that I have the Javascript in a separate file, while the fiddle acts as though the script is in the HTML file itself... I do want to  try to keep them separated still so do I have to do the click event through the DOM to achieve that?

Comment: No. It doesn't matter where you put the jQuery click handler as long as you're certain it's being hit. I would recommend, to get it working, you put the code in my answer at the bottom of your HTML page before `</body>` to ensure it's working. If it is, you know that the other place you had it isn't being reached.

Comment: Yep you were right :) Turns out a simple error **elsewhere** in my code meant that this wasn't being executed what so ever, so I just fixed that and problem solved! (I had gotten JQuery's `$(document).ready()` confused with `window.onload` and had written `document.onload`... It's always the little things) Anyway your answer still solved my original question so a tick for you my good sir! (Tick = Check mark if you're American ;) )

Answer (score 0):

You can take your second bloc of js code, Javascript function, and place it in a different class. then call it. Say for example you placed you code in a file called onclick.js then you'll call it in this form:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="onclick.js"></script>
```

and if you placed in a folder, say for example it's called myFolder, then you'll call it with:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="myFolder/onclick.js"></script>
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: But wouldn't that just move the issue to a different file or folder? I already have it in a separate javascript file, i guess I should have mentioned that beforehand, sorry. And when you say different class, what exactly do you mean? I didn't think there were any classes in Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

First what does `placeTile` really need? Because it is being called from a DOM event drop the notion that you need to give it a string in the first place. For example:

```
function placeTile(tile) {
  tile.removeClass('emptyTile');
  tile.addClass(['nought', 'cross'][currentPlayer]);
  currentPlayer = (currentPlayer + 1) % 2;
}
```

Now use event delegation. Set a click handler on the parent element and then look at the events `target` property to get the element that was actually clicked.

Live: http://jsbin.com/rahaba/1/edit?js,output

```
var board = document.getElementById('board');
board.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target === e.currentTarget) {
    return; // This is the parent div, we only want the children
  }
  if (e.target.tagName === 'DIV') {
    e.stopPropagation();
    placeTile(e.target);
  }
});
```

and in jQuery:

```
// Notice the extra 'div' selector.
$('#board').on('click', 'div', function() {
  placeTile(this);
});
```

Comment: I was half asleep when I wrote the answer apologies for the code errors, Fixed now